# Simultaneous launch of two processes

Tags: java, android, thread-synchronization

I need to run two processes simultaneously.
I wrote the code:

```
    public void starttwoprocessing () {
    final Thread tworunprocessing = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            FlashLight.onFlashResume();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);                      
                }
            });
        }
    });
    tworunprocessing.start();
}
```

First start:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
```

The second:

```
FlashLight.onFlashResume();
```

After changing places with the same result.
In this case, I get the first shot and the flash is started later.
`Thread.sleep(...);` does not help

How to start simultaneously flash, and immediately take a picture?
Thanks

---

written like this:

```
public class Launcher
{
    public void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {

        try {
        Process[] proc = new Process[2];
        proc[0] = new ProcessBuilder("FlashPreview.onFlashResumeStart()").start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        proc[1] = new ProcessBuilder("camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback)").start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
        }
        proc[0].destroy();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        proc[1].destroy();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
}
```

Called:

```
mk = new Launcher();
        try {
            mk.main(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Something I'm doing wrong.
Does not work at all, no crash, but wrote in the log:07-05 16:38:58.217: W/System.err(30934): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [FlashPreview.onFlashResumeStart()] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=9, SECONDARY_STORAGE=/storage/extSdCard:/storage/UsbDriveA:/storage/UsbDriveB:/storage/UsbDriveC:/storage/UsbDriveD:/storage/UsbDriveE:/storage/UsbDriveF, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/sdcard0, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/framework_ext.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/seccamera.jar, ANDROID_DATA=/data, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=8,66560, VIBE_PIPE_PATH=/dev/pipes]

Comment: I think it is not clear what is your question

Comment: about simultaneously. The standard Camera app, the flash fires in-sync with the camera shutter. I want the same result is achieved

Answer (score 2):

even using Threads your processes will runs after eche other. Using Threads means that second process no need to wait while first one is done. But easiest way how to fire two processes at the same time it is use [timeout or ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042760/how-to-launch-two-java-program-in-the-same-time-through-another-one)

Also it can be good idea to run second process in first one. As for me it the best solution.

P.S. privet, ne chasto yvidiw zdes svoih s ykrainu)))

Comment: privet,da est takoe, no tut proshe otvet poluchit, bez holivara.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
  FlashLight.onFlashResume();
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
  return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);         
}
}
```